# How does today's Google Doodle "force" fullscreen in iOS9 Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari, html5-fullscreen

Today Google has another quite complex game as their doodle: http://www.google.com/logos/2016/scoville/scoville16.html?hl=en

I'm pretty amazed at how well it works on mobile phones. In fact in one respect it works a lot better than I thought possible: We're currently working on some games and are having an issues with iOS9 Safari which makes it very hard to hide the address bar when the game is loaded. iOS7 allowed some scroll hacks, but those got removed and until today I thought it was impossible to "force" full screen in that browser. This doodle, however, does it perfectly.

I'm trying to find out what's going on, but I think I'm overlooking something. It can't be the HTML5 full screen API (which the doodle uses), since that's not supported in Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: "This doodle, however, does it perfectly." – what does it do perfectly? It doesn't go into fullscreen mode, that's for sure. So what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn It did when I tried. I don't have an iphone at hand to test right now, sorry. If I was actually wrong with my first assumption that would answer this question.

Comment: When you rotate iPhone to landscape the navigation and url toolbars get hidden automatically (at least in iOS 9), you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: @marekventur were you able to find how they did it. I am also looking for a way to go to full screen.